# How to check if user already register or not while registration in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, if-statement, keychainitemwrapper

I'm trying to check if a user is already registered or not in my app when registering. For every successful registration, I'm getting a UID in `LoginViewcontroller` url and I'm saving that UID in the keychain wrapper. I'm retrieving the UID value in `RegistrationViewController` regesterservice, but when I'm trying to check that UID I'm getting `nil` all the time. Why..? how to check if a user is already registered or not? Please help me.

In `LoginViewcontroller` login service, I'm saving the UID value like this:

```
self.Uid = json["id"] as? String
KeychainWrapper.standard.set(emailL ?? "", forKey: "user_email")
KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.Uid!, forKey: "Uid")
```

Here, in `RegisterViewController`, I retrieve the UID value. But for already registered persons, I'm also getting `nil in UID. Why?

```
do {
    let userId: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "Uid")
    print("login userid \(userId)")

    if userId != nil{
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "Title", message: "user exist", in: self)
    } else {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
        print("go to otp service!!!")
        self.otpField = json["otp"] as? Int
    }
} catch {
    print("error")
}
```

How can I query a UID of an already registered person?

Answer (score 1):

In the first block of code, the Uid variable from the json is different from the Uid property being set in the keychain wrapper.

```swift
var Uid = json["id"] as? String // `var Uid` is a local variable
KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.Uid!, forKey: "Uid") // `self.Uid` is a property on self
```

you can fix it by setting property to self instead of creating a separate variable

```swift
self.Uid = json["id"] as? String
KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.Uid!, forKey: "Uid")
```

edit:

I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you're saying. But I would try setting a breakpoint and debugging like this, and see which statement returns nil:

```
po json
po json["id"]
po json["id"] as? String
po self.Uid
po KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "Uid")
```

Comment: no actually i am using self.Uid = json["id"] as? String in first block of code.. if i do like that also getting nil.. pls help in the code

Comment: Try printing the contents of `json` and check that it has a String value for the "id" key. It's possible that it's nil and so an empty string is getting set in the keychain.

Comment: no i am getting all uid values KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.Uid!, forKey: "Uid") but     let userId: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "Uid")
 i am getting nil